# Assign most people their first choice based on a list of preferred choices

Tags: python, algorithm, grouping, preferences

Given a list of choices (say 100), each person in a list (say 30) has to choose 5 choices in the order they would like them to be assigned. How would I assign each person a choice making sure as many people as possible got their first choice (or highest preferred choice)?

Each choice has a variable limit on how many times it can be chosen e.g. choice 1 might be available to 3 people, choice 2 available to 1, choice 3 to 5 etc.

I am using Python to write the code but I'm interested in which algorithm I should use.  I found some suggesting Stable Marriage Problem but this requires that both sides have a preference and in my case only the people have a preference.  Another I found was the Assignment Problem but this required there to be an equal number of people to choices with each choice going to 1 person and again my problem has more choices than people with the added problem that 1 choice can potentially be available to more than 1 person

Comment: This seems like purely an algorithmic issue, so maybe it's better suited for http://cs.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @John: Are you going to accept an answer?

Answer (score 2):

This seems similar to, but not quite the stable marriage problem. Maybe that algorithm would work or could be adapted: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem

(Loads of code in different languages).

Answer (score 1):

You can model this as a network flow problem. Build a network with

1. a source node, a sink node, nodes for each person and nodes for each choice.
2. an edge between the source and each person (with capacity 1)
3. an edge between each person and the each choice she chooses with a capacity of 1
4. an edge between each choice and the sink with a capacity equal to the maximum number of times the choice can be selected.

Then assign weights to all the edges

1. weights of 0 for all the edges between the source and each person
2. weights of 0 for all the edges between the each choice and the sink
3. for each edge between a person p and any of her choices c, set the weights as follows: n^(5-rank(p,c)) where rank(p,c) is the position of c on p's ordered list.

Finally find a maximum cost maximum flow in the resulting network.

Answer (score 0):

If your only restriction is that:

> as many people as possible got their first choice (or highest preferred choice)

My suggestion would be a simple sorting operation.

You could sort by popularity `# requests for a choice - # of available spots` in their first choice, then the same for second choice and third, and so on. Go through each user and assign first choice if it is available, then flag them or remove them from the list. Repeat for second choice, third choice etc for all users who haven't been selected yet.

This approach would be advantageous because it accounts for uneven distributions of choice by giving preference to those who have chosen really popular or overpopulated choices. This bias would increase the likely-hood that as many people as possible get at least one of their choices. People who select the top 5 choices, for example will be practically ensured to get at least one choice where otherwise they might not have a chance. People who have a couple of unpopular choices `(# requests for a choice - # of available spots) <= 0` will likely be pushed into one of those unpopular choices, but at least they will get one of their preferred choices. People who have all unpopular choices will get what they want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Assignment Problem formulation if e.g. for a choice that is available 5 times you add 5 copies of it, and moreover add dummy persons such that the number of persons and choices is equal.